# Windows 8 WebView

Tags: xaml, webview

I have ran into problem, that WebVie is always on top, i have LoadingGrid (black background with image on it) it haz Z.Index =5.

First thing i show Loading screen, and when WebView finishes loading i hide Loading screen and fade in WebView.

But the problem is that WebView even with Opacity set to 0 - IS VISIBLE! And on top of my loading screen - is there a workaround? Because the only way i found to make WebView invisible set to collapsed - but then my effect doesn't have any reason...

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ShowHideWebView">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="HideWebView"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="ShowWebView">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="wv1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="18*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--
    <Button x:Name="bBack" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="bBackClick" >
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/back_button.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button> -->

    <WebView x:Name="wv1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LoadCompleted="wv1_LoadCompleted" Opacity="0" />
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Source="Assets/back_button.png" Tapped="backClick" />
    <Grid x:Name="LoadingScreen" Grid.Row="1"  Visibility="Collapsed" Canvas.ZIndex="5">
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Image Height="100" Width="100" Opacity="0.5" Source="Assets/loading.gif" Stretch="Fill">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="SpinningRotateTransform" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stick to `Visibility` property because when opacity is 0 at that time `WebView` would be part of visual tree and hence it will be on top of each element. While if it's collapsed it's no longer part of visual tree. I would recommend to try [`WebViewBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush) to show fade effect. When effect is over show `WebView`.